# Extend an array's length by a value. And then use averages to fill in the spots to create a smoothing effect

Tags: arrays, swift, algorithm

Sort of hard to explain in a title, but I am trying to extend an array by a certain multiple by calculating the mean of points in the array. It's not too difficult to extend it by 2, but I am struggling to extend it by a custom multiplier.

**Ex:**

let x = [3, 6, 7]

extend(array: x, multiplier: 3) ~~ Should be [**3**, 4.5, 5.25, **6**, 6.5, 6.75, **7**]

So the first "in-between" value is the mean of (3,6) and the next is the mean of (4.5, 6), then you move onto the next value and so on.

```
func extend(data: [Double], multiplier: Int) -> [Double] {
    var new = [Double]()
    var x = 0
    for i in 0..<(array.count*multiplier) {
        let value = data[x]
        new.append(value)

        if(data.count <= (x+1)) { break }

        let next = data[x+1]
        let mean = (value+next)/2
        new.append(mean)

        if(i%multiplier == 0 && i != 0) { x += 1 }
    }
    return new
}
```

Comment: So `[3, 6, 7]` becomes `[3, 4.5, 5.25, 6, 6.5, 6.75, 7]` not `[3, 4, 5, 6, 6.33, 6.66, 7]`?

Comment: Additionally, what do you mean _extend_? Size of? `[3, 6, 7].count = 3` and `[3, 4.5, 5.25, 6, 6.5, 6.75, 7].count = 7`. That is obviously not 3 times the size :P

Comment: Yes, Intend to use it for decimals so it can't just be incremented by whole numbers. I used "extend" and not multiply because yes, it is less than 3x this size, but you can't extend the last value because there is nothing to average it with.

Answer (score 0):

Since you only increment the first `originalArray.count-1` we only need to loop through those.

```
func extend(data: [Double], multiplier: Int) -> [Double] {
    var newData:[Double] = []
    for i in 0 ..< data.count-1 {
        let currentOriginalValue = data[i]
        let nextOriginalValue = data[i+1]
        let newValues = findHalfwayValues(firstVal: currentOriginalValue, secondVal: nextOriginalValue, times: multiplier-1)
        newData += [currentOriginalValue] + newValues
    }
    newData.append(data[data.count-1])
    return newData
}

func findHalfwayValues(firstVal:Double, secondVal:Double, times:Int) -> [Double] {
    var newData:[Double] = []
    var originalVal = firstVal
    for i in 0 ..< times {
        let halfway = findHalfway(firstVal: originalVal, secondVal: secondVal)
        newData.append(halfway)
        originalVal = halfway
    }
    return newData
}

func findHalfway(firstVal:Double, secondVal:Double) -> Double {
    return (firstVal+secondVal)/2
}

print(extend(data: [3, 6, 7], multiplier: 3)) // [3.0, 4.5, 5.25, 6.0, 6.5, 6.75, 7.0]
```

Here is another solution. Additionally, there is a slight bug in @Nick's solution where it does 1 more iteration than it should. Otherwise, it seems to work

Answer (score -1):

Solved:

```
func extend(data: [Double], amount: Int) -> [Double] {
    var new = [Double]()

    for i in 0..<data.count {
        let value = data[i]
        new.append(value)

        if(data.count<=i+1) { break }

        let next = data[i+1]

        var means = [Double]()
        for z in 0..<amount {
            if(z==0) {
                let mean = (value + next)/2
                means.append(mean)
            } else {
                let mean = (means[z-1] + next)/2
                means.append(mean)
            }
        }
        for m in means {
            new.append(m)
        }
    }
    return new
}
```

Comment: Code only answers are not always useful. Can you give some helpful explanation of what you did?